# Analog Clock in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

I have been reading Clean Code and yesterday I completed day 2 of [JavaScript 30](https://javascript30.com/). I tried to make the JavaScript I wrote for this as clean as possible. This is probably some of the cleanest code I've ever written, but now I'm wondering how it could be even better. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS + CSS Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand minute-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
const SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
const MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;

const DEGREES_PER_ROTATION = 360;
const SECONDS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION = 60;
const MINUTES_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION = 60;
const HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION = 12;

class Hand {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.completedRotations = 0;
  }

  updateRotation(lastNow, now) {
    if (this.hasCompletedARotation(lastNow, now)) {
      this.completedRotations++;
    }
    const degrees = this.calculateRotationInDegrees(now);
    this.element.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
  }
}

class SecondHand extends Hand {
  hasCompletedARotation(lastNow, now) {
    return lastNow.getSeconds() > now.getSeconds();
  }

  calculateRotationInDegrees(now) {
    const seconds = now.getSeconds();
    const secondsRotationProgress = seconds / SECONDS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    return (
      (secondsRotationProgress + this.completedRotations) *
      DEGREES_PER_ROTATION
    );
  }
}

class MinuteHand extends Hand {
  hasCompletedARotation(lastNow, now) {
    return lastNow.getMinutes() > now.getMinutes();
  }

  calculateRotationInDegrees(now) {
    const milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
    const seconds = now.getSeconds();
    const minutes = now.getMinutes();
    const millisecondsRotationProgress =
          milliseconds /
          MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND /
          SECONDS_PER_MINUTE /
          MINUTES_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const secondsRotationProgress =
          seconds / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE / MINUTES_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const minutesRotationProgress = minutes / MINUTES_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const totalRotationProgress =
          millisecondsRotationProgress +
          secondsRotationProgress +
          minutesRotationProgress;
    return (
      (totalRotationProgress + this.completedRotations) *
      DEGREES_PER_ROTATION
    );
  }
}

class HourHand extends Hand {
  hasCompletedARotation(lastNow, now) {
    return (
      lastNow.getHours() % HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION >
      now.getHours() % HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION
    );
  }

  calculateRotationInDegrees(now) {
    const seconds = now.getSeconds();
    const minutes = now.getMinutes();
    const hours = now.getHours();
    const hoursOnClock = hours % HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const secondsRotationProgress =
          seconds /
          SECONDS_PER_MINUTE /
          MINUTES_PER_HOUR /
          HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const minutesRotationProgress =
          minutes / MINUTES_PER_HOUR / HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const hoursRotationProgress = hoursOnClock / HOURS_PER_CLOCK_ROTATION;
    const totalRotationProgress =
          secondsRotationProgress + minutesRotationProgress + hoursRotationProgress;
    return (
      (totalRotationProgress + this.completedRotations) *
      DEGREES_PER_ROTATION
    );
  }
}

const hands = [];

const start = new Date();
let lastNow;
let now = start;

setupHands();
update();

function setupHands() {
  const secondHandElement = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
  const minuteHandElement = document.querySelector('.minute-hand');
  const hourHandElement = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

  const secondHand = new SecondHand(secondHandElement);
  const minuteHand = new MinuteHand(minuteHandElement);
  const hourHand = new HourHand(hourHandElement);
  hands.push(secondHand, minuteHand, hourHand);
}

function update() {
  updateTimestamps();
  updateClockHands();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function updateTimestamps() {
  lastNow = now;
  now = new Date();
}

function updateClockHands() {
  hands.forEach(hand => hand.updateRotation(lastNow, now));
}
```

[JSBin with everything](http://jsbin.com/teduqey/7/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I found a few improvements myself which have been made [here](http://jsbin.com/teduqey/9/edit?js). Namely I got rid of the unused start variable, replaced the lastNow variable with a lastUpdated field on the Hand class, and renamed the update function to animationLoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Too complex.

There is a very simple rule in all programming, KISS (Keep It Simple Simon (*)) and your code has strayed a long way from that rule.

Complexity is a breeding ground of problems, it is hard to maintain, more likely to be buggy, can be resource hungry, and more.

You started well by defining the `hand`, but adding a new class for each hand type is unnecessary. The only difference between them is the rate at which they move, so add that as a property or state and the element (or maybe just the style) that they use and the hand is fully defined.

### The CSS precision

There is the problem of CSS precision but that is easily fixed by getting the time at the start of the day and subtracting that from the current ms and does not need the extra rotation counter (not sure how long it needs to run for the second hand to start playing up again, but you can just reset that once a day if you plan on letting it run 24/7).

### Rewrite

You had about 114 lines of javascript which can easily be reduced to 20 and behave exactly the same. There is no point in adding all the const for time as they are truly constants and you will never be hunting around to change them (The irony of constants is that you define them so it's easy to change them, not because they never change). I personally would have reduced the rate values eg 360 / 3600000 = 0.0001 but that is a little obscure so left them as is.

```
;(() => {
    const DAY_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    const hand = (style, rate) => ms => style.transform = `rotate(${(ms * rate | 0) }deg)`;
    setInterval(() => requestAnimationFrame(display), 1000);
    const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    const start = (Date.now() / DAY_MS | 0) * DAY_MS;
    const $ = query => document.querySelector(query).style;
    const hands = [
        hand($('.second-hand'), 36 / 6000),
        hand($('.minute-hand'), 360 / 3600000),
        hand($('.hour-hand'), 360 / (12 * 3600000)),
    ];
    function display() {
        const ms = (Date.now() - offset) - start;
        hands.forEach(hand => hand(ms));
    }
})();
```

<sub><sub>(*) Yes I know but some people take it personally.</sub></sub>

Comment: While I agree that not every number deserves a named constant, one should also not fall into the trap of magical numbers. For example in your code it's hard for me to tell whether `36` is actually supposed to be `360` (like in other lines) because I'm not really sure what's the meaning of dividing it by `6000`. Using named constants helps us express that meaning in code.

Comment: It seems to me that this code is sneaking to the realms of code golf, where the readability is sacrificed for brevity. For example your use of binary OR operator. I understand binary operations, but it takes me a while to wrap my head around what that code is trying to achieve. Why not simply express your actual intentions by using `Math.floor()`.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo  I will stop my lazy use of bitwise operators  `val|~~~-(0**0)` yes much better.  Is `**` bad as well or should we use `Math.pow()` Don't you mean `Math.trunc()` as `Math.floor()` does not replace `|0` .

Comment: Indeed, `Math.trunc()` would be the correct equivalent of `|0`, but this code doesn't need to deal with negative numbers, so `Math.floor()` would work equally well. It's perfectly fine to use `**` operator for exponentiation, as that's its intended usage. While using bitwise OR for truncating a number to integer is more of a side-effect of bitwise operations in JavaScript. If you really have a task where you want to do some bit-shifting, then bitwise operations are perfectly fine.

Comment: @Rene All bitwise operators truncate, it is not a "side-effect", Only  `>>` `>>>` `<< ` "shift bits" though rotate, multiply, or divide are acceptable (eg 12.3 <<  4  is equivalent to `Math.trunc(12.3) * 16`) Bitwise operations are essential in any language, shying away from them because there is lack of understanding is not acceptable and only compounds the ignorance. You had to work it out and now you have a broader knowledge of the language, and next time you have a line stretching to far to the right you may opt for a `| 0` over the `Math.floor()`.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't express myself well. I have nothing against bitwise operations per se. I only have a problem when they're used for something else than their intended purpose. And I would argue that the purpose of binary OR (or any other bitwise operator) is not conversion from float to integer. It just so happens that JavaScript needs to convert the operands to integers because the binary operations don't make much sense on floating point values. Using binary OR for integer conversion is a clever trick, but clever tricks make code hard to understand.

Comment: @Rene I do not agree, there is no trick and it is not hard to understand. All JS programmers should know that bitwise operations convert doubles to a int32 (its JS 101) , they should also know that ints are significantly quicker than doubles. Do you know that you can not know if the result of `floor` is a double or int? There is no consistency between JS implementations. Using  `| 0` is ~2 times quicker than floor  and ~4 times quicker than trunc. `| 0` is no trick, it is part of the most basic JS understanding (its an operator!!! a fundamental indispensable  building block of the language)

Comment: I guess then we can agree to disagree. For me, not everything that's built into a language is necessarily a good thing to be used. I understand both `==` and `===` operators, but still prefer to always use `===`. Just like I understand both `|0` and `Math.trunc()`, but would always prefer the latter. Also, using one operator instead of another because of speed is a micro-optimization, which usually trades readability for questionable performance gains.Real performance benefits almost always come from writing a better algorithm.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo Yes to agree to disagree. Micro-optimizations on the best algorithm offer quantifiable performance gains, a huge competitive advantage. Don't underestimate the gains a few microseconds per operation can give when you accumulate that across all products and services in a world that laps up anything that reduces consumption. Every cycle on every device is a cost that someone must pay for.